# How to use androd Maps Bounds which adapts with Bottom Sheet

Tags: java, android, maps, bounds

In my project I have a method that draws a route inside of map and create a bounds for this route, the problem is, I need to create this bounds with the bottom sheet and not the entire screen!

First I open the Bottom Sheet:

```
private void openBottom(){
    if(latLngs != null){
        if(bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);
        }
    }
}
```

And then Draw and the bounds!

```
private void drawnNewRoute() {
    if(polyline == null){
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            po = new PolylineOptions();
            for(int i = 0, tam = latLngs.size(); i < tam; i++){
                po.add(latLngs.get(i));
                builder.include(latLngs.get(i));
            }
            String data = new Gson().toJson(latLngs);

            po.color(Color.BLACK).width(10);
            polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);

            ArrayList<LatLng> latlang = new ArrayList<>();
            latlang.add(latLngs.get(0));
            latlang.add(latLngs.get(latLngs.size() -1));

            mMarkerNewPosition = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(finalLocaltion).title(finalLocationName));
            mMarkerNewPosition.showInfoWindow();

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 120));

            location_display_incl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            stopLocation();
            InicialAddressTxt.setText(InicialAddress);
            double finalLat = latLngs.get(latLngs.size() -1).latitude;
            double finalLong = latLngs.get(latLngs.size() -1).longitude;

            try {
                ADRS = getAddress(finalLat,finalLong);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FinalAddressTxt.setText(finalLocationName);
            String finalComp = ADRS.getLocality() + "," + address.getAdminArea();
            FinalComplement.setText(finalComp);
            //zoomToCoverAllMarkersInMap(latlang);
    }
    else{
        polyline.setPoints(latLngs);
    }
}
```

But it keeps getting the whole screen and not just the "available" part of it!